# stack smashing detected when no return statement in function returning non-void

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc8

I have been debugging a crash in a program which aborts with the error `stack smashing detected`. I have narrowed down the crash to just one function which is:

```
static ssize_t a (const char *x, const char *y, size_t z) {
#ifdef SOME_FLAG
    return b(x, y, z);
#endif
}
```

Since I am not defining SOME_FLAG anywhere, the function essentially does nothing and exits **without** a return statement.

I observed that if I just add a `return 0` outside the `#ifdef #endif` block, the program doesn't abort (due to stack smash). The abort is also not seen if I define the function as `static void` instead of `static ssize_t`

Can the lack of a return statement cause stack-protector to trigger abort?

Comment: Sure.  It is undefined behavior to not return when the function is supposed to.

Comment: Well I did get the warning that I am supposed to return but what I am unsure about is how is this resulting in a stack overflow/corruption..

Comment: Undefined Behaviour (UB) allows the compiler to do _anything_.

Comment: is like to ask "what the undefined behavior does", forget that, just return 0

Comment: @NathanOliver: In C, falling through a function that is declared as returning a value is defined as equivalent to returning an arbitrary value if the caller never observes the value that was (not) returned.  This could sometimes be useful for functions that accept a "mode" parameter to select among various actions, only some of which would have anything meaningful to return.  If a caller that invokes `someFunc(2)` is never supposed to look at the return value, any effort `someFunc` might spend loading a return value would be wasted.

Comment: @supercat C++ is *not* C.

Comment: @NathanOliver It's not ub if the returned (well, not returned) value is never used.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: The question is tagged both C and C++.

Comment: @Swordfish For C++ it is: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/stmt.return#2.sentence-8

Comment: @sg1993 Please pick a single language.  C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: @NathanOliver Didn't see the C++-tag at first. For C it isn't ub when the value isn't used.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Given that many people who work with C++ also have to work occasionally with C, and vice versa, it's useful for people working in each language to know ways in which the other one differs.

Comment: Removed the C tag since my code is in C++. Also, to clarify, I was not using the return value anywhere..

Comment: *Also, to clarify, I was not using the return value anywhere.* – For C++ that doesn't matter. See NathanOliver's link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding C++:

If a function (other than `main`) declared to return a non-void value exists without return or throw, then the behaviour of the program is undefined.

> Can the lack of a return statement cause stack-protector to trigger abort?

Yes. The behaviour is undefined. Anything can happen.

Comment: In a worst-case scenario it may even appear to work (sometimes).

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's a bad scenario. Worst-case scenario (that has actually happened to my knowledge) for UB: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Therac-25 (Pedantic note: I'm not sure if it would be technically correct to call a race condition UB in context of assembly)